# Rust not creating function in lib extern FFI

Tags: rust, static-libraries, ffi

I have many Rust functions working perfectly across Ruby FFI.  But following directions from two different sites for creating a **free_array** method is not making the method available in the linked library.

This example is the working example of freeing a String returned from Ruby.

```
use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CString;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_string(s: *mut c_char) {
  unsafe {
    if s.is_null() { return }
    CString::from_raw(s)
  };  
}
```

And here are two attempts at implementing a way to free the memory of an Array.

```
use std::mem::transmute;
use ruby_array::RubyArray;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_array(ra: *mut RubyArray) {
  let _ra: Box<RubyArray> = unsafe{ transmute(ra) };
}

// OR

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_array(ptr: *mut RubyArray) {
  if ptr.is_null() { return }
  unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr); }
}
```

This results in an error:

```
Function 'free_array' not found in [/libfaster_path.so] (FFI::NotFoundError)
```

Here's the Struct I'm using and which gets created perfectly in to Ruby from Rust.

```
use libc;
use std::mem;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct RubyArray {
  len: libc::size_t,
  data: *const libc::c_void,
}

impl RubyArray {
  #[allow(dead_code)]
  pub fn from_vec<T>(vec: Vec<T>) -> RubyArray {
    let array = RubyArray {
      data: vec.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void,
        len: vec.len() as libc::size_t
    };  
    mem::forget(vec);
    array
  }
}
```

But that's not relevant as it's not the issue.  The issue is the method is not being made available in the library output for FFI to read from.  What's wrong with this?  Rust is happy and I've written many other methods in similar manner that work.  What makes this not found in the `.so` file?

The file is included in the main `src/lib.rs` with `pub mod` so there's nothing wrong there.  It's the same as the other working methods.

*I'll be posting a blog with much fuller implementation details later and I'll add a link to the comment section below for those who are interested.*

---

**Minor Update**

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with Rust.  I've used both Ruby's Fiddle and FFI to verify that this method couldn't be accessed where as other methods could be by both.

I grepped the binary and found the text showing the **free_array** method in the binary but apparently that's not compiled correctly to be read by FFI.

Comment: I've opened an issue on Rust's Github https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44459

Answer (score 0):

The information I provided was not enough to debug the issue.  The real problem was I had changed from building source from release to debug and had not updated the FFI linked library folder to reflect that.  So the code kept pointing at and old lib.